# Shallow Binding with static scope, is it possible?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, variable-binding, syntax-trees

I'm new in programming, I'm currently studying programming languages.

I'm trying to implement Shallow Binding with static scope, starting from an abstract syntax (producing a programming language based on Ocaml with static scope).

According to "Programming Languages: Principles and Paradigms" (Maurizio Gabbrielli Simone Martini) every lenguage with static scope also uses Deep Binding, which leads to my question. Is it even possible to implement a form of Shallow Binding given a static scope programming lenguage? If so, how?

The books seems to underline that this is not recommended, to cite "The choice of a shallow policy appears contradictory at the methodological level", without explaning.

Any help to understand these words and implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.